# How do I add custom headers with 'no-cors' enabled

Tags: javascript, api, cors, fetch-api

I have using fetchApi to make a post reqest:

```js
fetch('https:someurl.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        withCredentials: true,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'X-Signature': 'somecode'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
        })
    }).then....
```

I want to send 'X-Signature': 'somecode' in the header, but I found out with 'no-cors', I can't have any custom header.

I have tried including `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',` but still the header is not getting sent.

Comment: *I want to send 'X-Signature': 'somecode' in the header, but I found out with 'no-cors', I can't have any custom header.* You've answered your own question.

Comment: I am curious as to what solution did you come up with?

Answer (score 1):

The point of `no-cors` is that it lets you make requests that are allowable without CORS headers. CORS headers are set by the server, not the client.

`no-cors` doesn't let you set custom headers. If you remove `no-cors` and get CORS-related errors you need to fix this on the server-side.

I wrote more about no-cors here: https://evertpot.com/no-cors/

Comment: even if I safelist it, it wont work? like for example Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Custom-Header

Comment: The purpose of CORS is to remove cross-domain restrictions, so yes. But this needs to be done by the server.